# Integration in a region?

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

```
f[x_, y_] :=  NMinimize[{Sin[a x y], 1 < a < 5}, {a}][[1]]
NIntegrate[If[f[x, y] > 0, 1, 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

I want to perform integration in the rectangular region taking contribution only from those point where $f[x,y]$ is positive.

However, mathematica is not able to compute it.

I tried defining region, but mathematica is giving an error.

```
region = ImplicitRegion[ NMinimize[{Sin[a x y], 
  1 < a < 5}, {a}][[1]] >  0, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}]
```

Comment: Exact solution: https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/225038-Integration-In-A-Region

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `NumericQ` in the definition of `f`:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := NMinimize[{Sin[a x y], 1 < a < 5}, {a}][[1]]

AbsoluteTiming[
 NIntegrate[If[f[x, y] > 0, 1, 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 3]
]

(* {23.4154, 0.922105} *)
```

Comment: You can speed up code try:`f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NMinimize[{Sin[a x y], 1 < a < 5}, {a}, Method -> "NelderMead"][[1]];

AbsoluteTiming[
 NIntegrate[If[f[x, y] > 0, 1, 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]`

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: "NelderMead" is extremly fast, but evaluates the ` integralresult ==1`  , all the other methods give  `==0.922105`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann. Ok, in this case `NelderMead` is bad method. Maybe this: `f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  NMinimize[{Sin[a x y], 1 < a < 5}, {a}, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
    Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"][[1]];
AbsoluteTiming[
 NIntegrate[If[f[x, y] > 0, 1, 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 3]]`

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk: Thanks, I was surprised about the outlier "NelderMead" (without warning)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Please consider providing another answer with the observations in the comments here.

Answer (score 2):

I had to write the answer on [user's Anton Antonov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34008/anton-antonov) special request.

We can **speed up** a little the code by using method `SimulatedAnnealing` in `NMinimize` function and adding `PrecisionGoal` with low value.

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := NMinimize[{Sin[a x y], 1 < a < 5}, {a}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"][[1]];

AbsoluteTiming[ 
NIntegrate[If[f[x, y] > 0, 1, 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
MaxRecursion -> 3]]

(* {58.8097, 0.922105} *)
```

Using code [user's Anton Antonov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34008/anton-antonov) on my machine gives output with time:

```
 (*{192.335, 0.922105}*)
```

In the comment, what I wrote about method `NelderMead` in `NMinimize`.I don't know why gives a incorrect result.

---

**Addition:**

Using information obtained from the [book:Mathematica Navigator page: 749](https://www.elsevier.com/books/mathematica-navigator/ruskeepaa/978-0-12-374164-6)

I came to the conclusion, with **good** starting points `NelderMead` gives a correct result.

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
NMinimize[{Sin[a x y], 1 < a < 5}, {{a, 4, 5}}, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
Method -> "NelderMead"][[1]];
AbsoluteTiming[
NIntegrate[If[f[x, y] > 0, 1, 0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
PrecisionGoal -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 3]]

(* {59.6583, 0.922105} *)
```